# Get random items from range of list

Tags: python, algorithm, random

Let's say I have a unsorted set of items:

```
input = set([45, 235, 3, 77, 55, 80, 154])
```

I need to get random values from this input but in a specific range. E.g. when I have

```
ran = [50, 100]
```

I want it to return either 77 or 55 or 80. What's the fastest way to get this for large sets in python?

Comment: Does it have to be in pure Python? Numpy would (probably) make this much faster as you could mask parts of the available array based on your range. However, you should really show any way you have made this work before considering what might be the fastest.

Comment: Would numpy actually make it faster or only reduce the memory consumption?

Comment: I posted an answer about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't clarify whether you could or could not use `numpy` but also asked for "the fastest" so I'll include the `numpy` method for completeness. In this case, the "`python_method`" approach is the [answer given by Jean-François Fabre here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49393866/4799172)

```
import numpy as np
import bisect,random

data = np.random.randint(0, 60, 10000)
high = 25
low = 20

def python_method(data, low, high):
    data = sorted(data)
    start_index = bisect.bisect_left(data,low)
    end_index = bisect.bisect_right(data,high)
    return data[random.randrange(start_index,end_index)]

def numpy_method(data, low, high):
    return np.random.choice(data[(data >=low) & (data <= high)])
```

Timings:

```
%timeit python_method(data, low, high)
2.34 ms ± 11.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit numpy_method(data, low, high)
33.2 µs ± 72.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Obviously, though, you'd only `sort` the list once if you were using that function several times, so that will cut down the Python runtime quite to the same level.

```
%timeit new_data = sorted(data)
2.33 ms ± 39.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`numpy` would pull ahead again in cases where you needed multiple results from within a single range as you could get them in a single call.

EDIT:

In the case that the input array is already sorted, and you're sure you can exploit that (taking `sorted()` out of `timeit`), the pure python method wins in the case of picking single values:

```
%timeit python_method(data, low, high)
5.06 µs ± 16.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The un-modified `numpy` method gives:

```
%timeit numpy_method(data, low, high)
20.5 µs ± 668 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So, as far as I can tell, in cases where the list is already sorted, and you only want one result, the pure-python method wins. If you wanted multiple results from within that range it might be different but I'm benchmarking against `randrange`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that is you most up-to-date code, no? I also did include a caveat that the `sort` would only be performed once and included a `timeit` of that operation in isolation.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre in other words, I was trying to convey that the majority of the time in your approach tied up in sorting the list. If this was a one-off and the OP wanted, say, 50 values from a single range and then throw `data` away, they could use the `numpy` approach without incurring the sorting overhead.

Comment: yes, I saw that. But I suspect that `numpy` performs linear comparison, not bisection. So raw cpu power but more complex. Benching both on a sorted list would be interesting.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre on it

Comment: But I agree with your analysis. That's why I added an "update" chapter in my answer: how to update the list. Note: you already got my vote because a `numpy` solution is always welcome here. the bench part interests me a lot.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Having a pre-sorted array really makes Python pull ahead (`4.38 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`) of numpy running on an unsorted array. I want to make sure I use numpy correctly to give a fair comparison (I think the difference between them will dissolve for selecting a single value). I'll ping you once I have the results.

Comment: I like mind over muscle :) note that most implementations of `bisect` are compiled, which make them very fast as well. So what's left of pure python in the "non-numpy solution"? almost nothing.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ah, but I still have to make sure I come up with a proper equivalent for numpy to chew through in the case of a sorted array... :)

Comment: numpy may have methods to search in already sorted arrays as well. You tell me. I know zit about that :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre edited. I couldn't get numpy to pull ahead with a sorted array and to return a single value, which I'm not sure I'm so surprised about tbh. I tried several methods but they were becoming more convoluted for minimal gain.

Comment: Thank you two for providing such a comprehensive answer. I have to get several numbers in different ranges from the input values so I will use the pure python approach on a sorted list.

Comment: @larsl you are welcome, but you should probably accept his answer. I accidentally plagiarized the "pure python" code because I am familiar with benchmarking with Jean-François Fabre and I forgot to add that I was using his code directly. I will add attribution

Answer (score 6):

Using a `set` for this isn't the right way because elements aren't sorted. This would lead to a `O(N)` solution to test each element against the boundaries.

I'd suggest to turn the data into a sorted list, then you can use `bisect` to find start & end indexes for your boundary values, then apply `random.choice` on the sliced list:

```
import bisect,random

data = sorted([45, 235, 3, 77, 55, 80, 154])

def rand(start,stop):
    start_index = bisect.bisect_left(data,start)
    end_index = bisect.bisect_right(data,stop)
    return data[random.randrange(start_index,end_index)]

print(rand(30,100))
```

`bisect` has `O(log(N))` complexity on sorted lists. Then pick an index with `random.randrange`.

`bisect` uses compiled code on mainstream platforms, so it's very efficient besides its low complexity.

Boundaries are validated by performing a limit test:

```
print(rand(235,235))
```

which prints `235` as expected (always difficult to make sure that the arrays aren't out of bounds when using random)

(if you want to update your data while running, you can also use `bisect` to insert elements, it's slower than with `set` because of the `O(log N)` complexity + insertion in `list`, of course but you cannot have everything)

Comment: I have asked that this be the accepted answer. I should have made it clear that my "pure python" approach was using the code in your answer. Apologies!

Comment: no need to apologize. OP sometimes accepts the "other" answer for mysteriious reasons. Too many upvotes tend to scare people :) That's fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

input = set([45, 235, 3, 77, 55, 80, 154])
ran = [50, 100]

valid_values = []
for i in input:
    if ran[0] <= i <= ran[1]:
        valid_values.append(i)

random_index = randint(0, len(valid_values)-1)
print(valid_values[random_index])
```

Comment: this has `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: Also, here `print(random.choice(valid_values))` would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion that I find readable, easy to understand and quite short:

```
import random

inputSet = set([45, 235, 3, 77, 55, 80, 154])
ran = [50,100]

# Get list of elements inside the range
a = [x for x in inputSet if x in range(ran[0],ran[1])]

# Print a random element
print(random.choice(a))  # randomly 55, 77 or 80
```

Note that I have not used the name `input` for the defined set because it is a reserved built-in symbol.

Comment: I guess this performs well when calling the function once but the filtering creates a new list every time and would make it a much slower approach.